# How to write functional chord symbols with accidental roots

Tags: theory, chord-theory

How to write functional chord symbols of chord with roots with accidentals, for example: in C major scale, what is the functional chord symbol of the notes C#-E-G?

Answer (score 2):

#### Writing Roman numerals for chords with chromatic roots

Place the appropriate accidental in front of the Roman numeral: for example, #I or bII.

#### C#-E-G in C major

Chord symbols like #I are rare and generally don't have meaning within Functional Harmony. In most cases, such a chord will be labeled as a secondary chord. C#-E-G would be likely interpreted as vii<sup>o</sup>/ii, meaning it's the seven chord relative to the key of D.

Comment: (Revised comment) Why can't it be #Idim relative to the key of C?   We really shouldn't have to assume a new key-centre with every chromatic passing chord!

Comment: @LaurencePayne It could be #i, but that would be the rare exception within the framework of functional harmony.

Comment: @LaurencePayne I think Aaron's answer defends itself, since it says "likely".

Comment: Also, what is #I? Is it a function? Is it a tonic?

Comment: #I is the tonic of the key, raised by a semitone.  Its triad is diminished.    Happens all the time.  I - #Idim - ii - V7   is a cliché.

Comment: @LaurencePayne how can such unstable chord be called a tonic? The progression you mention includes a textbook example of viio/ii